# How to stop firebird process that was run as application in command line?

Tags: windows, firebird

We may run Firebird as application using command line:

```
firebird.exe -a -p 3050
```

Is that possible to shutdown the firebird process using command line too?

Comment: taskkill /im firebird.exe ? Perhaps followed by a /f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "easy" way to do it. If you started firebird.exe as an application, you can quit it by right-clicking on its icon in the taskbar, and selecting shutdown.

The only alternative is to kill it using taskkill, for example:

```
taskkill /IM firebird.exe
```

This has the following downsides:

- if you have active connections, this will produce a popup to ask for confirmation of shutdown (just like when doing this from the taskbar)
- if you have multiple firebird.exe processes, they will all be terminated

You can also force kill to shutdown, this will not produce the popup; open connections will be killed without prompting:

```
taskkill /F /IM firebird.exe
```

However, if you regularly need to do this, it might be better to install Firebird as a Window service that doesn't startup automatically. You can then control the service using `NET START` and `NET STOP` (or using instsvc).

For example, install Firebird as a service (require administrator command prompt):

```
instsvc install -demand -name firebird3
```

This creates a service called `"Firebird Server - firebird3"`

You can then start and stop the service using `NET START "Firebird Server - firebird3"` and `NET STOP "Firebird Server - firebird3"`, although this also requires elevated administrator privileges.